# Does calling google.maps.LatLng() contribute to any API limits?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I see the limits chart on Google Maps API and it says a limit of 25,000 map loads per day.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage#premium-usage-limits

But what about calling google.maps.LatLng()? 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng

I assume its just a function so there is no limit, but I want to make sure before I put my code into production.

Comment: Just check the developer console within your browser to see if a request is going out when you call that function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user2263572 for his comment. For anyone wondering how to see requests going out, go to:

```
Right-click > Inspect Element > Network
```

And from here you can observe the network traffic!